# How do I removed the keyring popup when I am accessing vino?

Tags: xubuntu, keyrings

I am running Xubuntu.  I was running headless fine before using tightVNC on windows and vino on Xubuntu. Now, after entering the password on the remote server, the following dialog pops on the local server (the one that usually don't have a monitor) before open the connection :

[image: Enter password for keyring Default to unlock]

Why is that dialog showing?

How do I get ride of it?

Comment: It seem to be a bug in vino server https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vino/+bug/562423, a bad decision from a package manager.

Comment: The issue is the password can be saved in the keyring or somewhere else.  The default was changed to save it in the keyring.

Comment: Try [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1639198)

Comment: My vino server was updated in October 2009, and it work fine until yesterday.  I try to reset the password on the command line a month ago (which failed, I borrow a monitor to reset it yesterday).  I suspect this issue is related to a something I typed on the command line trying to reset the password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vino/+bug/562423) in the Debian/Ubuntu package of vino server. There is a workaround in the bug comments, which I'm reproducing here. Rumour says it's only good for 10.04.

1. Open up Applications->Accessories->Passwords and Encryption Keys
2. Right click Passwords:login and unlock it.
3. You should be able to expand the tree and find a listing for vino. Right click and delete it.
4. Close Passwords and Encryption Keys.
5. Open gconf-editor as and navigate to /desktop/gnome/remote_access
6. Enter in your BASE64 encoded password into the vnc_password key.

   - Run `echo -n "your password" | base64`. Enter the output, even the equal sign.
7. Save the config and close the editor.
8. Log out, log back in, and you can now use your VNC client to connect to your machine without being first prompted with the keyring.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I am running Xubuntu, seem like Passwords and Encryption Keys is not there by default.  I am installing and I'll try to test again.

Comment: The packages for Passwords and Encryption Keys is seahorse.

Comment: However, I would put the -n in bold, it's easy to forgot and necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem. When you run `vino-preferences`, and check the box labeled **Require the user to enter this password:** the system will popup a menu asking for the default keyring.

It's easy, be sure to empty these fields, and accept the security warning that follows. Then write the viewer password as you want, reboot and you can connect without problems.

In the case you wrote something in these fields, you should remove the file:
`rm ~/.gnome2/keyrings/default.keyring` then reboot and redo `vino-preferences` as I said before.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
cd ~/.local/share/keyrings/
mv Default.keyring Default.keyring.backup
```

or you can even remove Default.keyring file, but better - rename. Now you will be asked to create new password. Do it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say click on "Details" in that same window and choose to the first option saying something like "start keyring when i login". It's by far the simplest and safest choice.

It took me like 2 hours to find that simple solution, i wonder how many people click on that option...

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @djeikyb did not work for me; when I did this, my VNC client could not connect (and I did use echo -n to base64 encode my password.)

Instead, I stopped vino-server, restored my ~/.gconf/desktop/gnome/remote_access/%gconf.xml (to undo the change completely), ran vino-preferences (from a console) and entered my connection password in the preferences dialog, then logged off/logged back in (which restarts my vino-sever).

My 'login' password is the default (in seahorse), and my 'default' keyring
does not have a vino entry.

Now my client can connect **and** I don't have to unlock my keyring.

(Note: I'm running the latest update for vino-server on Ubuntu 11.10;
I think some bugs have been fixed in vino)

Answer (score -1):

there is no Passwords and Encryption in Xubuntu menus . you should manualy add this .

your Solution is Here :

```
 http://www.geekyeric.com/?p=67
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: link goes nowhere now